# Resetting a PHP $_SESSION array with jquery function

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to reset a session array in php with a function in jquery using a button. I would use a submit but I don't want the page to refresh. I tried to send a `$.post` request leaving the variables and return blank, and then sending a variable so I could use $_session[''] = array() but none of it worked. I have searched and can't find much about it just a lot on sending strings.

Comment: Post your code. If you want to empty out the entire session, use `$_SESSION = array()`.  By doing `$_SESSION[''] = array()` (which is an error since the key can't be empty, but if it wasnt....) you are attempting to append an empty array onto the existing `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, empty string is totally valid key in array.

Comment: @DenysPopov Yikes, you're right. That's makes me a little sick.

Comment: It wasn't empty I was just showing an example... I used post for my forms because I am using jquery tabs and was using a button to add items to my array in php to send with my form data later... I just didn't want it to revert back to the first tab....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is very simple to stop the page from refreshing you need to tell js to disable the default event i use jquery for this here is my code

Html & js

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reseting a PHP $_SESSIO array with jquery function</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        function sessRest(){
            $.post("rest.php", {x: "9845621"}).done(function(data){
                alert("States: " + data);
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#target").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                sessRest();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <a href="#" id="target">Click to rest me</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

php code rest.php

```
<?php
session_start();

(string)$data = $_POST['x'];

if($data == "9845621"){
    $_SESSION['gx'] = array();
    return $_SESSION['gx']; //return the empty array to js
}else(
    return "error";
)


?>
```

I hope this helps .

Comment: @scottdarlint518, then edit your post and provide more info. Post your code for example.

Answer (score 0):

User below jquery to submit to php code

```
var requestData = { param: "value"};
$.ajax({
    url: your_url/session_change.php,
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json" or what ever,
    data: your_data,
    success: function (data) {

    }

});
```

Comment: I did that with the post and just wanted run a php page to reset a SESSION array that I had set... In case some one wants to reset the order in the middle of it.. thank you though

Answer (score 0):

You can end the session successfully on server side with an ajax call, but apart from reloading the page, you're not going to clear what information was loaded already on client side. The session information wont be there once you do reload, but there is no way around that.

You can, however, emulate what you want to do with javascript.

When you load your session information, echo it to the page as javascript variables, then you have full control on client side. Just beware of echoing sensitive information like passwords, obviously.

Comment: I used $_SESSION['products'] = array(); and it seemed to reset it after I sent it with mysqli... but I will use an array in javascript to store until I finish the order. Then I can just send the array using my current $.post function...

Comment: That does seem like a better solution. One of my older sites uses cookies to store shopping cart info, then my php script grabs that when they go to checkout. My newer site uses a temporary table on a database to hold shopping cart info so the user can move from device to device and still have their shopping cart with them. When they complete the order, the info on the temporary table is moved to the order table and their temp table is free to add more to cart again.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

your html file should contain this jQuery file:

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
         url: 'http://yourwebsite.com/session.php'
         }).done(function(data){
        if(data=='reseted'){
                     //do anything...
        }
        else {
                     //do anything...
        }
       })
    });
```

and in your session.php file:

```
<?php
    session_start();  
    session_unset();  
    if($_SESSION == FALSE){  
       echo 'reseted';  
    }  
    else echo 'no';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer was
jquery        $.post('reset.php');

in reset.php

$_SESSION['products'] = array();

?>
this reset my session array when the reset button was clicked with no page refresh...

I had done this originally and forgot to include my core.php in the reset.php which contained my start session()..
Thank you all for the help though.... great suggestions